# For error correcting coder, are there any other distance definitions beside hamming distance?

Tags: hamming-distance, error-correction

I am trying to get the distance of two binary numbers for error correcting. Although Hamming distance can find the number of different bits between two numbers, it does not indicate the absolute difference of two numbers. Are there any other distance definitions that describe the absolute difference between two binary numbers?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't understand your question: What is _the absolute difference between two binary numbers_?

Comment: For example, if I have A = b'1001, B = b'0001, the hamming distance would be 1. I think error correcting coder is generally based on hamming distance. I was wondering if it is possible to do error correcting based on the absolute distance (in this example, it would be 8 (1001 - 0001)).

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of coding theory where I am not an expert. However the answer for general-purpose digital systems is NO:

Here, all information is represented by bits that are grouped into bytes, words, etc..
But a group of bytes can represent anything, an instruction, data, and individual bits can even control e.g. an elevator. Thus, bits don't have an intrinsic "importance", and error detection (has a bit changed?) and error correction (which bit combination is closest to the received one?) is done for all bits in the same way.

A completely different situation is when a group of bits has an intrinsic meaning, e.g. represent a number. Here bits are are of different importance. In special-purpose digital systems, this could be exploited to protect more important bits better than others, but I don't have an example.
A trivial case is however special-purpose analog electronics, say an old phone system. Here, your idea to protect more important information better, is realised: Low induced voltages don't disturb loud voices.